# Python PyQt pixmap update crashes

Tags: python, image, pyqt, python-imaging-library, qpixmap

I have a simple PyQt application.  You can cycle through a folder of images using pageup and pagedown keys.

I am using the pixmap of a QLabel to display the images.  The following logic actually works until you comment the processEvents call.

[image: python crash]

Any ideas on the cause of the crash and why adding processEvents prevents the crash?

```
# Python version: 2.7.9 
# Qt version: 4.8.6
# PyQt version: 4.11.3

import sys
import os 
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageOps
from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import Qt

imagefolder = "C:/Users/alan/Desktop/imagefolder"

class QExampleLabel (QtGui.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parentQWidget = None):
        super(QExampleLabel, self).__init__(parentQWidget)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI (self):

        self.imagelist = []

        for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(imagefolder):
            path = path.replace("\\", "/") 
            for file in files:
                base, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
                if ext.lower() == ".jpg":
                    jpg = path + "/" + file
                    self.imagelist.append(jpg)

        self.i = -1

    def keyPressEvent(self, keyevent):
        event = keyevent.key()
        if event == QtCore.Qt.Key_PageUp:
            self.backward()
        if event == QtCore.Qt.Key_PageDown:
            self.forward()

    def forward(self):
        self.i = self.i + 1
        if self.i >= len(self.imagelist):
            self.i = len(self.imagelist) - 1
        self.displayimage()

    def backward(self):    
        self.i = self.i - 1
        if self.i < 0:
            self.i = 0
        self.displayimage()

    def displayimage(self):   
        photo = self.imagelist[self.i]
        img = Image.open(photo)
        mysize = (260,260)
        method = Image.NEAREST if img.size == mysize else Image.ANTIALIAS
        self.cropimage = ImageOps.fit(img, mysize, method = method, centering = (0.5,0.5)) 
        qim = ImageQt(self.cropimage)
        pix = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qim)
        self.setPixmap(pix)  
        QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()  # comment this line to see setPixmap crash

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myQExampleLabel = QExampleLabel()
    myQExampleLabel.show()
    myQExampleLabel.resize(260,260)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is probably caused by garbage-collection, because you are not keeping an explicit reference to the Qt image object. When you create a pixmap from a QImage, the underlying data will remain shared, so use the QImage copy constructor to get an explicit reference, and then keep it alive until the pixmap is no longer needed:

```
self._img = QtGui.QImage(qim)
pix = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(self._img)
```

**UPDATE**:

Using the test case, I was able to eliminate the crash by simply keeping a reference to the original `ImageQt` object:

```
self.qim = ImageQt(self.cropimage)
pix = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(self.qim)
self.setPixmap(pix)
```

Or, more simply, by using [QPixmap.detach()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#detach):

```
qim = ImageQt(self.cropimage)
pix = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qim)
pix.detach()
self.setPixmap(pix)
```

Comment: After adding QApplication.processEvents() ... the crash appears to have gone away.  I wonder if this also supports the garbage-collection theory?

Comment: @panofish. You need to provide a [proper test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that allows other people to try to reproduce the problem. I gave what is the most **probable** cause of the error in my answer, but there's no way I can debug things any more accurately because I can't run the **real** code that has the problem.

Comment: Good idea... I updated the source example to a full stand alone example.  You should be able to see the problem now.  If you comment the processEvents() call, then the application will crash.

Comment: @panofish. See my updated answer for some solutions.